# How to scrape multiple pages avoiding error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code below works with only one page, but I want multiple pages it brakes.  I am not sure what I a doing wrong.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

lst_url = []
for n in range(0,5):
    url = f'https://www.tableau.com/solutions/customers?region=All&industry=All&department=All&page={n}'
    lst_url.append(url)

   
for x in lst_url: # Ask hosting server to fetch url

    pages = requests.get(x)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pages.text, 'html.parser') #parse
    cus_info = soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'card__details'}) #find all tags <img...>
    list_c = []
    for info in cus_info: 
        customer_info = {
        'cust_name': info.find('img', {'class':'card__logo'})['alt'],
        'cust_use' : info.find('h3', {'class':'card__title'}).text,
        'cust_url': 'www.tableau.com'+ info.find('a', {'class':''})['href'],
        'cust_logo' : 'www.tableau.com'+ info.find('img', {'class':'card__logo'})['src']} 
        list_c.append(customer_info)
 
df_c = pd.DataFrame(list_c)
print(df_c)
```

Thank you in advance for your help

I troed the code below and I was expecting something like this:

[image]

code works only for one page  `[for n in range(0,1)]`, but if change it to more than one  `[for n in range(0,35)]` it breaks and shows this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/folders/jy/frz19nzj13q7ysgxkzb7zc2c0000gn/T/ipykernel_3085/1487842660.py", line 19, in <module>
    'cust_name': info.find('img', {'class':'card__logo'})['alt'],
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - May take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. This will help us to identify your issue more easily next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Always check if your elements are available before calling the attributes:

```
'cust_name': info.find('img', {'class':'card__logo'})['alt'] if info.find('img', {'class':'card__logo'}) else 'No Image',
```

##### Example

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd

list_c = []

for n in range(0,35): # Ask hosting server to fetch url
    url = f'https://www.tableau.com/solutions/customers?region=All&industry=All&department=All&page={n}'
    pages = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pages.text, 'html.parser') #parse
    cus_info = soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'card__details'}) #find all tags <img...>

    for info in cus_info: 
        customer_info = {
        'cust_name': info.find('img', {'class':'card__logo'})['alt'] if info.find('img', {'class':'card__logo'}) else 'No Image',
        'cust_use' : info.find('h3', {'class':'card__title'}).get_text(),
        'cust_url': 'www.tableau.com'+ info.find('a', {'class':''})['href'],
        'cust_logo' : 'www.tableau.com'+ info.find('img', {'class':'card__logo'})['src'] if info.find('img', {'class':'card__logo'}) else 'No Image'
        }
        list_c.append(customer_info)
df_c = pd.DataFrame(list_c) 
df_c
```

##### Output

|  | cust_name | cust_use | cust_url | cust_logo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Logo for World Food Programme | UN World Food Programme promotes organization-wide data literacy to advance food security worldwide | [www.tableau.com/solutions/customer/un-world-food-programme-promotes-organization-wide-data-literacy](http://www.tableau.com/solutions/customer/un-world-food-programme-promotes-organization-wide-data-literacy) | [www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_220x60/public/companies/wfp_logo_0.png?itok=VUCFlWZn](http://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_220x60/public/companies/wfp_logo_0.png?itok=VUCFlWZn) |
| 1 | Logo for Verizon Communications | Verizon uses Tableau to reduce support calls by 43%, enhancing customer experience | [www.tableau.com/solutions/customer/verizon-reduces-calls-enhances-customer-experience-with-tableau](http://www.tableau.com/solutions/customer/verizon-reduces-calls-enhances-customer-experience-with-tableau) | [www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_220x60/public/companies/verizon_logo.png?itok=Hgt5ZJc4](http://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_220x60/public/companies/verizon_logo.png?itok=Hgt5ZJc4) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 313 | Logo for MillerCoors USA | MillerCoors discovers sales opportunities, selling more product to retailers with Tableau Cloud | [www.tableau.com/solutions/customer/millercoors-satisfies-their-thirst-better-data-tableau-online](http://www.tableau.com/solutions/customer/millercoors-satisfies-their-thirst-better-data-tableau-online) | [www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_220x60/public/companies/miller_coors_-_a_mc_company_1.png?itok=HhsaBzvq](http://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_220x60/public/companies/miller_coors_-_a_mc_company_1.png?itok=HhsaBzvq) |
| 314 | No Image | Masabi makes city transport smarter with help from Tableau | [www.tableau.com/solutions/customer/masabi-makes-city-transport-smarter-help-tableau](http://www.tableau.com/solutions/customer/masabi-makes-city-transport-smarter-help-tableau) | No Image |